# Sphinx --buildstops how with special chars?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx, keyword

I am using SphinxSearch service for creating a searchable index and it works great... superfast with relevant results!

now we want to fnish opur autosuggestion tool and would like to mine popular keywords from our DB...

indexer --buildstops works fine for us... wit --buildfreqs options is almost perfect...

but it lacks two things...

1. the words are in plain english charset, no special utf8 chars, that ARE in our DB (like ščž)

How can I get correct words? any suggestions?

1. It only gets keywords butnot phrases... we would like also popular phrases with no more than 3 words....

is there an alternative, fast way to mine the DB table for this phrases?
We are using PHP/mysql combo